# How to export and import a single Sequelize instance in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, caching, singleton

I am using `Sequelize` with `Node.js` and `TypeScript` to connect to a `PostgreSQL` database. I want to export and import a single `Sequelize` instance throughout my application, so that I have a single connection to the database.

I have seen many examples where the `Sequelize` instance is exported directly from a module, like this:

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import { DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_PORT, DB_USERNAME } from ".";

export default new Sequelize(
  `postgres://${DB_USERNAME}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}`
);
```

However, I am using a function to get the `sequelize` instance instead, like this:

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import { DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_PORT, DB_USERNAME } from ".";
let sequelize: Sequelize;

const getDB = async () => {
  if (sequelize) return sequelize;
  try {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(
      `postgres://${DB_USERNAME}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}`
    );
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log(`PostgreSQL is connected to ${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}`);
    return sequelize;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", error);
  }
};

export default getDB;
```

I am doing this because I want to make sure that the `sequelize` instance is created only once and after the database connection is established. I also want to handle any errors that may occur during the connection.

Is this a good way to `export` and `import` a single `sequelize` instance in `Node.js`? Will this create a new instance every time I import it from another module? Or will it reuse the same instance that was created the first time?

For example, if I import and use the `sequelize` instance in another module like this:

```
import getDB from "./db";

const sequelize = await getDB();

const User = sequelize.define("User", { ... });
```

Will this create a new `User` model every time I import it? Or will it use the same User model that was defined the first time?

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: No point in declaring `let sequelize` outside of the function and using a singleton pattern, if you are going to *call* the function already and export a promise, instead of exporting the function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So you mean I need to return `getDB` instead of `getDB()`?

Comment: Iff you want to call `await getDB()` in every module where you import it, yes.

Comment: I see. But the most of examples are using the first approach, why? Does this support singleton? Some of the references make me sense that node.js supports module cache. I'm so confused.

Comment: Well because it's much simpler to just export the instance itself? The module cache makes the whole module a singleton already.

Comment: Umm, if so, when to use singleton?

Comment: You mean the factory function that returns the singleton? That should only be used when you need to initialise it lazily, i.e. upon first use.

Comment: I have just understood. Thank you for your explanation - @Bergi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not point in makeing this pattern of yours, as if you export anything from module, it becomes singleton of some sort (explained in documentation). Thats why all examples experted sequelize once, and all shared the same database

---

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This
> means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get
> exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
> file.
>
> Provided require.cache is not modified, multiple calls to
> require('foo') will not cause the module code to be executed multiple
> times. This is an important feature. With it, "partially done" objects
> can be returned, thus allowing transitive dependencies to be loaded
> even when they would cause cycles.

- 

> To have a module execute code multiple times, export a function, and
> call that function.
> *

> Modules are cached based on their resolved filename. Since modules may
> resolve to a different filename based on the location of the calling
> module (loading from node_modules folders), it is not a guarantee that
> require('foo') will always return the exact same object, if it would
> resolve to different files.
>
> Additionally, on case-insensitive file systems or operating systems,
> different resolved filenames can point to the same file, but the cache
> will still treat them as different modules and will reload the file
> multiple times. For example, require('./foo') and require('./FOO')
> return two different objects, irrespective of whether or not ./foo and
> ./FOO are the same file.

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: I have just understood. Thank you for your explanation - @Seti.